# Increment count over rows with conditional restarting

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to increment a count that restarts from 1 when a condition in an existing column is met.

For example I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(10, 100, 200, 300, 87, 90, 45, 80), 
                 x2 = c("start", "a", "b", "c", "start", "k", "l", "o"))
```

I would like to create `x3` that starts counting from 1 each time that `x2 == "start"`.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
   x1    x2 x3
1  10 start  1
2 100     a  2
3 200     b  3
4 300     c  4
5  87 start  1
6  90     k  2
7  45     l  3
8  80     o  4
```

I'm guessing there are existing functions in R that give a general solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using base R:

```
df$x3 <- with(df, ave(x1, cumsum(x2 == 'start'), FUN = seq_along))
```

gives:

```
> df
   x1    x2 x3
1  10 start  1
2 100     a  2
3 200     b  3
4 300     c  4
5  87 start  1
6  90     k  2
7  45     l  3
8  80     o  4
```

---

Or with the `dplyr` or `data.table` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(x2 == 'start')) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = row_number())

library(data.table)
# option 1
setDT(df)[, x3 := rowid(cumsum(x2 == 'start'))][]
# option 2
setDT(df)[, x3 := 1:.N, by = cumsum(x2 == 'start')][]
```

Comment: My solution with base R turned out to be quite similar to yours. So here is another variation: `ave(1:nrow(df), cumsum(df$x2 == "start"), FUN = rank)`

Comment: how would you modify the code if I want an end instead in x2. e.g. end = 4, k = 1 instead of start = 1

Comment: @JervisChionh See [the comment I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397952/sequencing-reset-in-r?noredirect=1#comment89773177_51397952) under your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another base R method:

```
df$x3 <- sequence(diff(c(which(df$x2 == "start"), nrow(df)+1)))
```

which returns

```
df
   x1    x2 x3
1  10 start  1
2 100     a  2
3 200     b  3
4 300     c  4
5  87 start  1
6  90     k  2
7  45     l  3
8  80     o  4
```

`sequence` takes an integer vector and returns counts from 1 to each of the vector entries. It is fed the length of each count using `diff` to calculate the difference of the positions of the start of each sequence. Because of this, we have to include the value of the position after the final row of the data.frame, `nrow(df)+1`.