# How do I create a variable that increments by 1 based on the value of another variable?

Tags: r

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
id <- rep(1, 9)
start_over <- c(rep(NA, 3), "yes", NA, "yes", rep(NA, 3))
dat <- data.frame(id, start_over)
```

I.e.,

```
    id  start_over
1   1   NA
2   1   NA 
3   1   NA
4   1   yes
5   1   NA
6   1   yes
7   1   NA
8   1   NA
9   1   NA
```

How would I create a new variable that increments by one each each time start_over is "yes".

i.e.,

```
    id  start_over   assignment
1   1   NA           1
2   1   NA           1
3   1   NA           1
4   1   yes          2
5   1   NA           2
6   1   yes          3
7   1   NA           3
8   1   NA           3
9   1   NA           3
```

Comment: `cumsum(dat$start_over == "yes") + 1`

Comment: @Jaap, that is going to fail due to `NA`

Comment: @bouncyball just replace `==` with `%in%`; see also my answer

Comment: Anyway, this is highly likely a duplicate. Can't find a good one ATM, so feel free to post one

Comment: this question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517669/increment-count-over-rows-with-conditional-restarting (and it has an accepted answer from @Jaap :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NA` can be identified just with `is.na()` function, and then `cumsum()` the boolean values.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(x = cumsum(!is.na(start_over)) + 1)

#   id start_over x
# 1  1       <NA> 1
# 2  1       <NA> 1
# 3  1       <NA> 1
# 4  1        yes 2
# 5  1       <NA> 2
# 6  1        yes 3
# 7  1       <NA> 3
# 8  1       <NA> 3
# 9  1       <NA> 3
```

Comment: Not much really dplyr about that; I suggest that it's clearer to show what you're suggesting first and then show how to add the column with mutate. Any of the other answers could be easily "dplyr"d in the same way.

Comment: @Aaron Sorry!! It's my fault. It's not a dplyr issue indeed. I edited the description.

Comment: So why somebody downvotes my answer? Just because I use dplyr tool?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. For clarity, you might also note that the OP wanted it to increment on "yes", so you're assuming the values are only "yes" or NA. The other answers are more general. (Not my downvote, btw, but that could be the reason.)

Answer (score 5):

A small improvement of my comment:

```
dat$assignment <- cumsum(dat$start_over %in% "yes") + 1
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dat
>   id start_over assignment
> 1  1       <NA>          1
> 2  1       <NA>          1
> 3  1       <NA>          1
> 4  1        yes          2
> 5  1       <NA>          2
> 6  1        yes          3
> 7  1       <NA>          3
> 8  1       <NA>          3
> 9  1       <NA>          3
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure why (__and it certainly isn't worth a downvote from me__), but I sort of have a philosophical disagreement with using `%in%` to get around `NA` values.

Comment: @bouncyball No reason to have a philosophical disagreement with using `%in%` (imo at least); it is basically the same as `match(dat$start_over, "yes", nomatch = 0)` (see `getAnywhere('%in%')`).

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `cumsum` function:

```
cumsum(dat$start_over == "yes" & !is.na(dat$start_over)) + 1
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

We're checking to see if `start_over` equals "yes" and is not `NA`. If these conditions hold, we'll return a 1, otherwise it will return 0. We need to add `1` to the `cumsum` otherwise the assignment will start at 0.

```
dat$assignment <- cumsum(dat$start_over == "yes" & !is.na(dat$start_over)) + 1

#   id start_over assignment
# 1  1       <NA>          1
# 2  1       <NA>          1
# 3  1       <NA>          1
# 4  1        yes          2
# 5  1       <NA>          2
# 6  1        yes          3
# 7  1       <NA>          3
# 8  1       <NA>          3
# 9  1       <NA>          3
```