# R increment by 1 for every change in value column and restart the counter

Tags: r

I would like to find a way to do very similar to this question. 
[Increment by 1 for every change in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column/29661388)

**But i want to restart the counter when var1 = c**
using
`df$var2 <- with(rle(as.character(df$var1)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))*`

results in column var 2

```
var1 var2 Should be
   a    1   1
   a    1   1
   1    2   2
   0    3   3
   b    4   4
   b    4   4
   b    4   4
   c    5   1
   1    6   2
   1    6   2
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42517669/5325862

Comment: @camille - I don't think that Q covers the `rle` part. Practically the same logic though.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah there are a lot of posts with small mechanical variations but similar logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` you can use `rleid` to get a run-length-id for `var1` within each group.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, var2 := rleid(var1), by = cumsum(var1 == "c")]
df

#    var1 var2
# 1:    a    1
# 2:    a    1
# 3:    1    2
# 4:    0    3
# 5:    b    4
# 6:    b    4
# 7:    b    4
# 8:    c    1
# 9:    1    2
#10:    1    2
```

and using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(var1 == "c")) %>%
  mutate(var2 = cumsum(var1 != lag(var1, default = first(var1))) + 1)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1", "a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: using dplyr i get below error                                                                                       
Error: Column `+...` must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 192840

Comment: @Slubee - I can confirm the above code works in dplyr. Are you sure you are referencing the right variables?

Comment: Not sure what might be wrong then because like @thelatemail it works for me too. Here are few steps to check. 1) Does the `data.table` solution work for you? 2) Try referencing it with package name explicitly. `dplyr::mutate`. 3) Try it in fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the OP's code with `rle` in `base R` with `ave`

```
df$var2 <- with(df,  as.integer(ave(as.character(var1), cumsum(var1 == 'c'), 
       FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))
df$var2
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 1 2 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1", "a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```